# Google Maps API v3 click event listener called twice

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

On a default google map (API v3, firefox) the following click event listener gets called twice:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "rightclick", function(event) {
        alert('rightclick!');
});
```

Why? And whats the fix?

I've checked the QA [Google Maps Api V3: click event firing twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490151/google-maps-api-v3-click-event-firing-twice) but that did not fix the issue.

**UPDATE**: using console.log instead of the alert works as expected - listener called only once!?!

Comment: [Works fine](http://jsbin.com/efuqod/edit#preview). Tested on `Firefox 10.0.1`, and on `Chrome 20.0.1132.57`.Are you sure,that you didn't add 2 listeners?

Comment: Your example works. The only difference is that I'm injecting the JS to the end of the page. Also, using 'click' works as expected. Aaarg..